# Installing and Starting QGIS server on Windows 7

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7, server

I have downloaded and installed QGIS server as per the instructions on the web page  https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows, and have installed apache too. I have apache running. But in testing the QGIS server with the GetCapabilities phrase, I get 
Error message: End of script output before headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
with an Error 500.

I have searched for advice on the web, but it all seems to either replicate what was on the Getting Started webpage, or is old - 2012 to 2015 - and does not reflect what I have. Can anyone shed some light on a 2020 installation and setup of QGIS server please?

Comment: What I am also finding is that a lot of the statements of configuration are in unix format with unix / linux commands. But I am on windows so do not understand what to do.

Comment: I have updated the httpd-vhosts.conf file to include the following definitions - <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
Alias /qgis/ "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/"
<Directory "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/">
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost> - and now when I try the  GetCapabilities statement the browser 'downloads' the qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe file.  So that's progress I guess, but I am poking and hoping, as they say.

Comment: The lack of response leads me to conclude - along with the fact that any information I can find on the internet is over five years old - that QGIS server is defunct. Maybe just on Windows 7, maybe altogether. But the silence is disappointing.

Comment: The qgis team is doing an effort to improve the QGIS server documentation. Check the latest (testing) version: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows.